# Spring boot security and multipart file upload failling

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, multipart

Actually, I am facing an error while using Spring Boot version 2.7.10. I have implemented JWT Spring Security, and initially, everything was working fine. However, when I tried to retrieve an image as input using a multipart file, it resulted in the following error:

```
2023-07-03 11:13:57.706 ERROR 12008 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile[0]->org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile["inputStream"]->java.io.FileInputStream["fd"])
```

To provide more context, when I removed Spring Security from the controller, the code worked successfully. Here is an example of the controller without Spring Security:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@PostMapping("/upload")
public void uploadImage(@RequestParam("productImage") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

  System.out.println("Success uploading image file.");

}
```

For further understanding of the security configuration, I have attached the GitHub link below: https://github.com/prakash-aathi/authentication-authorization

I would appreciate any help or insights regarding this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: That controller is for posting an image **not** receiving an image. Also just posting randomg methods without the context of a class isn't really helpful.